# Magento : Admin Form Input Type "file" Value not Working

Tags: admin, magento-1, forms, file-upload

In magento admin edit form section, file attribute value is empty.
my file buttons code is :-

```
$fieldset->addField('actionc', 'file', array(
            'label'     => 'Upload',
            'name' =>'actionc',
            'disabled' => false,
            'readonly' => true,
            'tabindex' => 1


        ));

   $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
```

How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IN your `form.php` file's `_prepareForm()` method add `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` in `$form` variable I think you miss that thing

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl(
            'adminhtml/updatestock/save',
            array(
                '_current' => true,
                'continue' => 0,
            )
        ),
        'method' => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
    ));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
```

**Edit**
 update for Controller

```
// mychanges
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
if($id){
    $objectModel->load($id);
    $imgName = $objectModel->getActionc();
}
// end my changes
$uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('actionc'); 
$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('pdf'));
$uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false); 
$path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'pdf' . DS; $imgName = time().$_FILES['actionc']['name']; 
$uploader->save($path, $imgName); 
$postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); 
$objectModel = Mage::getSingleton('ghrix_copymerge/merge'); 
$postData['actionc']=$imgName; 
$objectModel->setData($postData)->save();
```

Comment: Hi  Murtuza Zabuawala, its already added

 $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
            'id'        => 'edit_form',
            'action'    => $this->getUrl('*/*/save', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))),
            'method'    => 'post',
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ));

Comment: @KirmalBrar is your problem with edit ??

Comment: yes.. when i save the form after edit , it genrates an error. Its just because of browse buttons value is null.

Comment: @KirmalBrar provide your saveController code

Comment: $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('actionc');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('pdf'));
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'pdf' . DS;
    $imgName = time().$_FILES['actionc']['name'];  
    $uploader->save($path, $imgName);
    $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $objectModel = Mage::getSingleton('ghrix_copymerge/merge');
    $postData['actionc']=$imgName;
    $objectModel->setData($postData)->save();

Comment: $objectModel->save();
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The action has been saved.'));
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
                return;

Comment: @KirmalBrar please check my updated code

Comment: Its not working for me